# How do you use socket.ntohs(0x0003) protocol with python SOCK_RAW on Ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, packet-sniffers, raw-sockets

I get an OSError from Python when I use `ntohs(0x0003)` as the protocol argument for a SOCK_RAW socket on Ubuntu.

```
  File "sniffer_all.py", line 44, in main
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0003))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 134, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I checked the /etc/protocols file, and it lists 3 as the GGP :

```
...
ggp 3   GGP     # gateway-gateway protocol
```

I do not know why this error occurs if the protocol is configured. I am running python with sudo, so I should have no access issues.

Replacing `socket.ntohs(0x0003)` with another protocol, such as `socket.IPPROTO_UDP`, fixes the error, but limits which traffic the socket can handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `sudo` or root is required if you want to use raw sockets, but you are calling `socket()` incorrectly. `socket()` takes arguments in *host byte order* but by calling `ntohs()` you convert the 8 bit GGP protocol value of `3` to the 16 bit value `768` which is wrong because the maximum possible protocol value is `255`.

You can either do it like this

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, 3)
```

or in a more readable way

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.getprotobyname('ggp'))
```

Comment: Second, I read the doc concerning ntohs() @ 
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socket.html which agrees exactly with what you say here. However, I wonder for what purpose ntohs() exists.

Comment: It's one of the available functions to change the byte order, mostly used when you want to send data over a network. You can read more about this here https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socket.html#socket.ntohs and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness